# Fubini extension and mean of random variables

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, game-theory

There is an atomless probability space $(\mathbb{I},\mathfrak{I},\eta)$ representing a set of agents indexed by $i\in[0,1]$, such that the probability space is the Lebesgue unit interval. Each type receives a payoff $x_{i}$ with has a distribution $F(\mu,\sigma)$, being continuous with a support $[\underline{x},\bar{x}]<\infty$. Is the following correct?
$E[\int_{0}^{1}x_{i}~1_{\{x_{i}\geq \hat{x}\}}~di]=\int_{\underline{x}}^{\bar{x}}\int_{0}^{1}x_{i}~1_{\{x_{i}\geq \hat{x}\}}~di~f(x)~dx=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\underline{x}}^{\bar{x}}x_{i}~1_{\{x_{i}\geq \hat{x}\}}~f(x)~dx~di=\alpha\mu$

where $\hat{x}$ is some real value and I define $\alpha\equiv\int_{0}^{1}1_{\{x_{i}\geq \hat{x}\}}~di$.

The above is correct only if Fubini extension holds. These are my references: [Sun, 2006](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022053104002224) and [Sun, 2009](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022053108000768)

Comment: What is the meaning of all those differently-fonted $x$s, and what is random inside that very first expectation?

Comment: All $x$ are the same. In the first expectation, the sum of $x_{i}$ over all $i$ is a random variable.

Comment: So your equation is saying the expectation of something (which is a number) is equal to $\alpha \mu$, but your definition of $\alpha$ seems to be a function of $X_i$ (hence a random variable).  So this looks like a type-error.  It is impossible for that equation to hold since the left-hand-side is a different type of thing than the right. Of course, $\alpha$ uses an integral of terms that still have the mysterious font.  You may want to start with the convention that random variables have capital letters.

Comment: Assuming $X_i$ is the same for all $i$, call it $X$, and let us replace $\hat{x}$ with $c$ for simplicity, it looks like you are trying to compute $$E[X1_{\{X\geq c\}}]=E[X|X\geq c]P[X\geq c] $$ and if $X$ has PDF $f_X(x)$ this is equal to $\int_c^{\infty} x f_X(x)dx$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am looking for the expected value of the **sum** of $X_{i}$ over a continuum $i\in[0,1]$.  $X_{i}$ are not the same for all $i$, they are independent draws from a distribution.

Comment: You are integrating the $X_i$ over a continuous variable $i$.  Why should that integral be defined, and how is it defined, and/or why should $X_i$ be measurable in $i$?

Comment: Inferring from your comment: 
$E[\int_{0}^{1}x_{i}~1_{\{x_{i}\geq c\}}~di]=\int_{\underline{x}}^{\bar{x}}\int_{0}^{1}x_{i}~1_{\{x_{i}\geq c\}}~di~f(x)~dx=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\underline{x}}^{\bar{x}}x_{i}~1_{\{x_{i}\geq c\}}~f(x)~dx~di=
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{c}^{\bar{x}}x_{i}~f(x)~dx~di=?$

Comment: My question is whether this can be defined? Are there minimum conditions for which it can be measurable? 
The problem originates from game theory (large aggregate games) for continuous players to some extent discussed in the references.

Comment: I would hesitate to define the integral of uncountably many independent random variables. Anyway, I do no t know how to do it. You might do better using a sum, taking the sum to infinity if you want.

Comment: $\alpha$ is the proportion of agents having a payoff above the threshold which is a random variable. I was thinking that by Law of Large Numbers it will be $1-F(c)$

Comment: The law of large numbers deals with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.  Intuitively, if $(X_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ are uncountably many mutually independent $\mathcal{U}[0,1]$ variables then I would expect the function $X_t$ (defined over $t \in [0,1]$) to be almost surely nonmeasurable, so $\int_0^1 1_{\{X_t \leq 1/2\}}dt$ would not be clearly defined. It would not be Riemann integrable, likely not Lebesgue either. There are ways to define the integral of any nonnegative function such as this but I don't think the answer will be $1/2$.